# Javascript: Capture swipe gesture using ontouchstart with iOS VoiceOver turned on

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, accessibility, wai-aria

We are developing an app which uses swipe gestures left and right to navigate content. For blind users using VoiceOver screen reader, the gesture is stolen by VoiceOver. This is a problem because the swipe gesture is the main feature of our app, and works nicely for blind users (but VoiceOver is needed for some other buttons).

We are developing in HTML5 javascript with Cordova/PhoneGap.

Ideally we would like to disable VoiceOver event trapping or disable VoiceOver within a region (ie a DIV).

Apple iOS is the main target but ideally also it would use standards such as HTML5 ARIA as we want it to work on Android also with other screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We came up with a workaround, which works for our use case. I've pasted the relevant part from my [Speaking Email blog](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/helping-blind-users-read-email-mike-nelson/) about how we achieved this:

> The big problem is that VoiceOver takes over the swipe gestures, and a
>   fundamental part of our app is what we call the "email slider" where
>   you navigate emails by swiping left and right.
>
> We managed to solve this by presenting the email slider as an ARIA
>   "tabset", which is a component that happens to be navigated by swiping
>   left and right. We named the tabs by the title of the email (eg "Email
>   from Fred Flintstone") so the user can quickly flip between emails and
>   hear VoiceOver read out the email title. A couple of seconds after the
>   user stops changing tabs (ie swiping left and right), we then trigger
>   our own text-to-speech engine to read out the email content nicely as
>   usual. So we managed to present a swipe left and right interface using
>   VoiceOver and WAI ARIA standards.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: the solution provided below is not optimal, it would be better to provide a different solution from gestures.

There is currently no way to programmatically turn the VoiceOver gesture interception. The only way is to get the user to use the iOS gesture passthru. In order to enable this, your gesture region must be focussed and have the role="application" attribute.

[An example can be seen here](http://dylanb.github.io/datepicker/datepicker.html)

To use the iOS gesture passthru, you double-tap and hold for one second. The VoiceOver outline will disappear and then any of the drag or swipe gestures can be used (you cannot use any gestures that require the finger to be raised because this disables the passthru).

As of my most recent testing with iOS 8, the application role is required. The solution linked works on all iOS versions up to and including the most recent version (9.2).

You will have to inform VoiceOver users how to use the passthru by supplying a screen reader text with instructions.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. I tried it and I couldn't actually figure out how to do it! As you say it is far from ideal and to be honest I think it would create as many problems as it solves. Got any other ideas?

Comment: Ps. I read your blog post, thanks for writing about this stuff - doesn't seem there is an actual solution to my problem though http://unobfuscated.blogspot.co.nz/2013/11/accessible-javascript-gestures.html?m=1

Comment: The real solution is not to rely upon gestures as pointed out in my note at the beginning

Comment: Yeah I guess i could create an invisible button that screen readers will find but sighted users won't see. Not ideal but should enable better accessibilty given the gesture won't work when voiceover is on.

Comment: Ideally you should create some controls that a voice recognition/keyboard only user could also use

Answer (score 0):

keeping 4 finger anywhere and swiping with one finger over the swipable area will also work. I tried it on a carousel

Comment: Interesting. Not great usability though